what does it mean by u direction when talking about radars?
I was watching a tutorial on radar systems, and it talked about u direction, without explaining what they mean by that. From the context, it appears that they mean azimuth direction. Just to clarify, does u direction mean the azimuth direction?

They are almost surely referring to the $u/v$ representation of angles. These are often useful since they map azimuth and elevation angles to the "forward" hemisphere of an antenna, which is often what is desired in radar systems. In this space the angles are restricted in both azimuth and elevation to $[-90^\circ, 90^\circ]$.
Given an azimuth angle $\text{az}$ and elevation angle $\text{el}$, the $u/v$ coordinates are:
$$u = \cos(\text{el})\sin(\text{az})$$
$$v = \sin(\text{el})$$
They are not independent of each other so care must be taken to not think of one or the other strictly as being the azimuth or elevation axis The only time this is true is along a principal axis:
If the $\text{el} = 0$, the $u$-coordinate does indeed function as the "azimuth" coordinate via the sine function, but then $v = 0$ regardless of what the azimuth is.
When $\text{az} = 0$, then the $v$-coordinate functions as the "elevation" coordinate again via the sine function, but then $u=0$ regardless of what the elevation is.
For the intermediate angles, things are no longer as clear. Let's say $\text{az}=45^\circ$ and $\text{el}=45^\circ$, then $u=0.5$ and $v=0.7071$. Without having a handy calculator on-hand or experience using these coordinates, it's less intuitive on what exactly the values mean compared to using polar angles directly.
According to the math, you could think of $v$ as the elevation coordinate, but $u/v$ coordinates aren't nearly as useful if you're only considering elevation (or azimuth for that matter). Since one usually is analyzing both, $v$ might be intuitive on its own but you have to contend with the values of $u$ which are also dependent on $\text{el}$.

oh, I didn't know that transform was "canonical"; I thought it was something specific to what I learned in my Radar lectures in University (don't even know anymore which of these)

Yeah it's pretty standard. There's some variations depending on how you define the coordinate system of course but the idea is the same.

Not generally, no. Typically, radar system designers take care to define directions somewhere in their documentation; and it's a bit more common to use $\theta$ for elevation and something like $\phi$ for azimuth; but conventions differ.
So, if $u$ being azimuth seems a reasonable inference from context, that might be it.
Note that radar algorithms generally do not care which angle is which, so it's thoroughly possible your $u$ is simply "the" direction in which something is happening, and not specifically azimuth or elevation.
